# Google Site - Navigation Tag

Tags: google-workspace, google-sites

i am making a website using google site and i am trying to use navigation tags to make navigation shortcuts to a specific title in my page, i can target the page to do a navigation tag but not titles and if i copy the link it just opens a new tab

Do you guys have any idea how i could make this ?
Ex: Clicking on the white "Clan Akimichi" would result in a navigation to the corresponding title

[image: Example of what i am trying to do]